# Flexible programing for inverse function or root finding in Freepascal

Tags: function, pascal, procedure, freepascal, variant

I have a huge lib of math functions, like pdf or cdf of statistical distributions. But often e.g. the inverse cdf can be only calculated numerically, e.g. using Newton-Raphson or bisection, in the latter we would need to check if cdf(x) is > or < then the target y0.

However, many functions have further parameters like a Gaussian distribution having certain mean and sigma, so cdf is cdf(x,mean,sigma). Whereas other functions, such as standard normal cdf, have no further parameters, or some have even 3 or 4 further parameters.

A similar problem would happen if you want to apply bisection for either linear functions (2 parameters) or parabolas (3 parameters). Or if you want not the inverse function, but e.g. the integral of f.

The easiest implementation would be to define cdf as **global** function f(x); and to check for >y0 or global variables.
However, this is a very old-fashioned way, and Freepascal also supports **procedural parameters**, for calls like x=icdf(0.9987,**@cdfStdNorm**)
Even overloading is supported to allow calls like x2=icdf(0.9987,0,2,@cdfNorm) to pass also mean and sigma.
But this ends up still in **two** separate code blocks (even whole functions), because in one case we need to call cdf only with x, and in 2nd example also with mean and sigma.

Is there an **elegant** solution for this problem in Freepascal? Maybe using variant records? Or an object-oriented approach? I have no glue about OO, but I know the variant object style would require to change at least the headers of many functions because I want to apply the technique not only for inverse cdf calculation, but also to numerical integration, root finding, optimization, etc.

Or is it "best" just to define a real function type with e.g. x + 5 parameters (maybe as array), and to ignore the unused parameters? But for me it looks that then I would need many "wrapper" functions or to re-code all the existing functions (to use the arrays, even if they are sometimes not needed!).

Maybe macros can help as well? Any Freepascal hints are very welcome!

Comment: Anonymous methods would be the natural way to do this, but fpc doesn't have them. Unless they have been added recently.

Comment: Thanks David, but I need indeed a fpc solution, and fpc is not yet offering anonymous methods. It seems the easiest way is defining icdf (or integral or rootfind, etc.) with a variant record keeping x and the parameters, and also the function itself as entries. Based on this we can also write a "universal" evaluation function to get f(x,...) for all cases. But for this I need to setup 1st a variable of such universal type, and pass it to icdf function.  Further hints are still welcome.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Without anonymous methods you'd need to make manual closures. Procedural `of object` types is how I would do this. Methods of records. Your procedural type would by `type TCalcFunc = function(X: Double): Double of object;` and you'd implement with methods of records. The record would contain the extra parameters. You ought to be able to work the details out from there, I hope.

Comment: Why not just several (global) function overloads (or even functions with different names)? The more general ones just call the more specific one -- or a special, non-public one -- with some default or nil parameters. Yes, each one will have its own function body, but what is so bad about that? The real algorithm(s) only have to be implemented once. The others just shuffle around a few parameters and call that general one. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @Rudy Yes, I think you misunderstood the question. It's about how to implement partial application.

Comment: @David: Your record with methods approach might be one way to implement it, but it would require writing a new record type and an associated calc func for each different application. More or less like implementing anonymous methods and their closures by hand (like writing functors in C++). That can be pretty tedious and not necessarily very elegant anymore (anonmeths would be much more elegant, IMO). But without anonmeths, I guess there is no really elegant solution for this.

Comment: @rudy It is the way to implement it. It's how anonymous methods operate.

Comment: @David: I know how anonmeths operate (except that they are -- hidden -- interface implementations, to make their lifetime management automatic). But if you must implement them manually, that is not very elegant anymore. As I said, I guess there is no elegant way (yet) to do this in FreePascal.

Comment: @rudy Lifetime management isn't really the issue. That could be done many ways. In Delphi it was but with existing tooling. For good reason. They key is that there is an instance of a class that holds the captured variables and that instance's life coincides with the a non method. Without compiler support the next cleanest way is as I described.

Comment: @David: I didn't say or mean that your record with methods woulnd't work, or isn't clean, just that in Delphi, they use interfaces. And that if you must implement this manually, it loses the elegance anonmeths provide, IMO, even if it is the only (or almost only) clean way. That was no criticism on your solution, just a remark that it would be more elegant if the language provided anonmeths or similar.

Comment: Anonymous Methods are mainly important if the execution context of the function is potentially different and you must package all relevant data. (like e.g. tthread.queue). For this, a reference based solution like nested functions is more natural. Even if FPC had anonymous methods, I'd use nested functions. You can then even pass arrays without copying them. Moreover anonymous methods have several usage gotchas, while nested functions have only one, don't keep a reference and call it after the function that got it as parameter returned.

Comment: @Marco: Nested functions, really? I don't know how these are referenced in FPC, but in Delphi that would be nearly impossible (probably possible using a hack). What is wrong with anonymous functions? They automatically capture the local variables and parameters. Nested functions don't do that, so you could only use them locally, and they would still require an extra pointer to reference the local frame. Using nested functions in Turbo Vision was already a hack.

Comment: Nested functions (as parameters) are clean if you support it properly. FPC has support (and e.g. can do the TV thing cleanly).  The parent framepoint is invisible, and such procvars are a different (two pointer) type, just like procedure of object(or do you object to that too?).   As said capture is unneeded in this case (needing extra allocation), and nested functions are probably faster and you can pass the same function multiple times in the nested case, I don't really see why one would use anonymous methods if one had proper support for both.

Answer (score 1):

If you make it a **(function .. of object)**, mean and sigma could be part of the class, and the function could internally just access it. Only the really changing parameters during the iteration would be parameters. (read: x)

*Anonymous methods* as talked about by David and Rudy is a further step to avoid having to declare a class for each such invocation, but that is convenience thing and IMHO not the core of the question. At the expense of declaring the class, your core code is free of global variable use and anonymous methods might also come with a performance cost, depending on usage.

Free Pascal also supports **[nested functions](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse17.html)** (function... is nested), which is the original Pascal closure-like way which was never adopted by Pascal compilers from Borland. A nested procedure passed as callback can access local variables in the procedure where it was declared. The Free Pascal numlib numeric math package uses this in some cases for similar cases like yours. For math it is even more natural.

Delphi never implements old constructs because borrowing syntax from other languages looks better on bulletlists and keeps the subscriptions flowing.

Comment: it was actually adopted by Borland, just not as a type (`is nested`), only as a concept. In Turbo Vision, it was used for some routines with callbacks, like `TList.FirstThat()`. Because the functions were nested, they required some extra handling inside `FirstThat()` and co, to get a pointer to the outer frame.

Comment: page 141ff in the following: https://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_borlandturVersion6.0TurboVision1990_16007263/Turbo_Pascal_Version_6.0_Turbo_Vision_1990_djvu.txt

Comment: I know Turbo Vision and the objects unit  (TCollection.foreach iirc also had it)  Actually the FPC TV and objects unit still use the hack. Compatibility and it is simply older. "Is Nested" is only available in released versions since a few years, and TP compatibility was fairly complete in 2003.